# How to calculate the distance between 2 point in c#

Tags: c#

I would like to calculate the distance between 2 point by using this formulae https://m.wikihow.com/Find-the-Distance-Between-Two-Points. But how do I write the formulae into it. How can I change the var to double? Because I cannot perform the mathematic operation because it the array is var
The following is my sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Console1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt1= ConvertToDataTable(@"C:\Users\manchunl\Desktop\Sample1.txt", 10);
            DataTable dt2= ConvertToDataTable2(@"C:\Users\manchunl\Desktop\Sample2.txt", 10);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt1.AsEnumerable())
            {
                string.Join(",", row.ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()));
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in dt2.AsEnumerable())
            {
                string.Join(",", row.ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()));
            }


            foreach (DataRow row1 in dt1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row2 in dt2.Rows)
                {
                    var array1 = row1.ItemArray;
                    var array2 = row2.ItemArray;

                    if (array2[4].Equals(array1[4]))
                    {
                        var x1 = array1[7];
                        var y1 = array1[8];
                        var x2 = array2[7];
                        var y2 = array2[8];



                    }
                }
            }


            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
            Console.Read();
        }


        public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable(string filePath, int numberOfColumns)
        {


            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

            for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++)
                tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + (col + 1).ToString()));


            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                var cols = line.Split(null);

                DataRow dr = tbl.NewRow();
                for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < numberOfColumns; cIndex++)
                {
                    dr[cIndex] = cols[cIndex];

                }

                tbl.Rows.Add(dr);

            }

            return tbl;
        }

        public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable2(string filePath, int numberOfColumns)
        {


            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

            for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++)
                tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + (col + 1).ToString()));


            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                var cols = line.Split(',');

                DataRow dr = tbl.NewRow();
                for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < numberOfColumns; cIndex++)
                {
                    dr[cIndex] = cols[cIndex];

                }

                tbl.Rows.Add(dr);

            }

            return tbl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "because it the array is var" Eeeeh, what? Hard to understand what you´re saying. What is `ItemArray`?

Comment: `double distance = Math.Sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));` in case of Euclidian distance

Comment: `var` is not a type itself, it just represents the implicit type. `array1` is the exact same type as `row1.ItemArray`.

Comment: It show Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

Comment: You have to post complete code here so we can understand it

Comment: So how can I get the value inside the array1[7] as double in order for me to perform the mathematics operation?

Comment: If `var` is confusing, don't use it...use the actual type instead. Perhaps that will make it clearer. What is the datatype of `array1[7]`?

Comment: I have update my code. Check and see

Comment: Please remove `var` from your code and replace it with the actual type so we can all see what types you're using here.

Comment: it seems `array1` and `array2` are of type `object`, right?

Comment: `var` is not a type itself. You have some fundamental misconceptions about C#. Please read up on C# concepts, particularly types. An array is a collection of types, so an array cannot be a `double`, but it can contain `double`s, (a `double[]`. `var` is shorthand that allows you to not write the actual type in your code, but the type is inferred by the compiler.

Comment: ya, how can I change it to actual datatype.

Comment: What are the values present in x1, x2, y1, y2?

Comment: I can't declare var array1 = row1.ItemArray; as its actual datatype

Comment: It show the value same as in txt file for example: x1: 130

Comment: No you misunderstand. If I have `var x = 2;`, `x` is not the type of `var`, `x` is type of `int`. The compiler automatically assigns the type for you. `var` just makes it easier to write code. By changing it from `var` to `int`, nothing is changing from the program's point of view.

Comment: So what should I change? I try int array1 = row1.ItemArray; but it not allow

Comment: When you hover over `row1.ItemArray`, it should tell you what data type it is. Otherwise, you can click on it and press `F12` to go to the definition. Get to know exactly what the methods you're calling do, and what types they return. Then you can manipulate the types appropriately. And try not to use `var` unless it's obvious what the type is (for example, `var name = "Frank";` is clearly a string, and `var pet = new Dog();` is clearly a `Dog` type, so using `var` in these cases makes sense).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Math functionality to calculate slope between two points

```
int distX = int.Parse(x2) - int.Parse(x1);
int distY = int.Parse(y2) - int.Parse(y1);

double result = Math.Sqrt(distX * distX + distY * distY)
```

[Sqrt()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [Pow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netframework-4.7.2), both are static functions of Math class.

Using Pow function

```
double result = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(distX, 2) + Math.Pow(distY,2))
```

Comment: Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

Comment: @appleorange, what values present in x1, x2, y1, y2

Comment: the actual value same as in txt file the integer value.

Comment: @appleorange Then parse it to integer. I updated my answer please check. I hope it will work.

Comment: Still can't. The x1,x2,y1,y2 there always got problem. I try solve the above part from var to int but it always show me cannot convert object type  :(

Comment: I try change to int x1 = int.Parse(string.Format("{0}", array1[7]));  it works!

Comment: Actually consider works. Bexause im asking the way to calculate instead of finding the way how to declare